# Pivot SQL table with text rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am trying to pivot a microsoft SQL database table but i can not get it to work. The examples that i can find are with numbers and add or join them.

This is what i got so far, but with little succes:

```
select *
from 
(
  select CODE, LangID , Text
  from dbo.REJECT_CODES
) src
pivot
(
  Text
  for LangID  in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

This is an example of a table that i want to pivot:

```
    Code    LangID  Text
--------------------------------------------
    1       1       Text1
    1       2       Text2  
    1       3       Text3
    1       4       Text4
    2       1       Text5
    2       2       Text6
    2       3       Text7
    2       4       Text8
```

And this is the result that i want to get:

```
    Code    TextA    TextB    TextC    TextD
----------------------------------------------
    1       Text1    Text2    Text3    Text4
    2       Text5    Text6    Text7    Text8
```

Comment: Just try it. You'll see that the examples are *not* about numbers. You have to put *something* in the cells though using an aggregate function. Where does that `Text1` come from? What is `TextA`?

Comment: Please post *actual* examples of the input data and desired result. Bear in mind that PIVOT doesn't work with an arbitrary number of columns. The cell values it generates *have* to be aggregates - they are the result of grouping the input by the row/column values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that is the big problem, i cant get this pivot function to work because all the examples are with numbers. My SQL knowlegde is not high too. Text1 is just data from an existing table as shown above, TextA is a column name of the table to create.

Comment: that "just" is what the question is about. *What* is TextA and where does it come from? Where do the *column* values come from? And what do you want to display in the cells? Only MIN/MAX work right now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I feel TextA is nothing but LangID in form of alias.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 'Prabhat G' is right, it is a just a column name that links the LangID and the text together. Maby i should have been more clear in my question, but i have the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
create table #temp (code int, languageID int, text varchar(10))
    insert into #temp values 
    (1,1,'Text1'),
   (1,2,'Text2'), 
   (1,3,'Text3'), 
   (1,4,'Text4'), 
   (2,1,'Text5'), 
   (2,2,'Text6'), 
   (2,3,'Text7'), 
   (2,4,'Text8')




select CODE, [1] As TextA, [2] As TextB, [3] As TextC, [4] As TextD
from 
(
  select CODE, LanguageID , Text
  from #temp
) src
pivot
(
  max(Text)
  for LanguageID  in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

op:

```
CODE        TextA      TextB      TextC      TextD
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           Text1      Text2      Text3      Text4
2           Text5      Text6      Text7      Text8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with an aggregation function like max:

```
declare @tmp table(   Code int,    LangID int, Text nvarchar(50))


insert into @tmp select 1,1,'Text1'
insert into @tmp select 1,2,'Text2'
insert into @tmp select 1,3,'Text3'
insert into @tmp select 1,4,'Text4'
insert into @tmp select 2,1,'Text5'
insert into @tmp select 2,2,'Text6'
insert into @tmp select 2,3,'Text7'
insert into @tmp select 2,4,'Text8'

select * from @tmp

select *
from 
(
  select CODE, LangID , Text
  from @tmp
) src
pivot
(
  max(Text)
  for LangID  in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) piv;
```

result:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| CODE |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 | Text1 | Text2 | Text3 | Text4 |
|    2 | Text5 | Text6 | Text7 | Text8 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```